# My Boolean In Another Script Won't Change State

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, boolean

thank you for reading this. I am quite confused why for some reason this code will not set live round to true when the laser spawns, but it will set the spawn origin to the correct game object and detach it from the parent, anyone got anything? And before you ask, no I don't set live round to false anywhere until I destroy the laser itself.
Thank you for any help you have!

```
private void Start()
{
   if (gameObject.name == "Big Laser(Clone)")
   {
       spawnOrigin = GetComponentInParent<BigShip>();
       spawnOrigin.liveRound = true;
       transform.parent = null;
   }
}
```

Comment: unity is not my domain of knowledge, but I can tell you nobody will be able to guess what happens in other parts of your code. please debug your program (there are watches which will break into the debugger whenever the value of `liveRound` changes, for example), then provide a minimal, complete example so the problem could be reproduced.

Comment: @dlatikay Good call debugging it with vs, it never occurred to me to do that when using unity. I'll try that and come back with more info

Comment: Thank you so much, god do I feel stupid for not using vs debugging. You have saved me a lot of frustration and time my friend all the best to you @dlatikay!

Answer (score 0):

If you sure didn't change your variable in code, I think this problem here is you get component spawnOrigin not correct. Just check spawnOrigin is correct component you want to get by Debug.Log or set break point in visual studio.

Comment: I did check it via the print function and even made the spawn origin public as to be able to click it in the editor and see what it is cached to and everything seems correct... Thanks for the help though!